# i am not able to run ng build --configuration production

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is the error i am getting please help

error: src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'fuse-progress-bar' is not a known element:

1. If 'fuse-progress-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fuse-progress-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1

```
src/app/app.component.ts:19:18
  19     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/app.component.ts:19:18
  19     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:4:5 - error NG8001: 'vertical-layout-1' is not a known element:
1. If 'vertical-layout-1' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'vertical-layout-1' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

4     <vertical-layout-1></vertical-layout-1>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/app.component.ts:19:18
  19     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:24:29 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nisch/sweech-web-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts' is not a module.

24 import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:74:14 - error NG1010: Value at position 30 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
Value could not be determined statically.

74     imports: [
               ~
75         BrowserModule,
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
117         VerticalLayout1Module
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
118     ],
  ~~~~~

src/app/app.module.ts:116:10
  116         !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Unable to evaluate this expression statically.
src/app/app.module.ts:116:10
  116         !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
  Unknown reference.


Error: src/app/helper-services/auth.service.ts:4:29 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nisch/sweech-web-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts' is not a module.

4 import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/helper-services/interceptor.service.ts:4:29 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nisch/sweech-web-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts' is not a module.

Error: src/app/reducers/index.ts:8:29 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nisch/sweech-web-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts' is not a module.

8 import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/main.ts:5:29 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nisch/sweech-web-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts' is not a module.

5 import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: did you import fuse-progress-bar on app.module.ts?

Comment: i think you want export the fuse-progress-bar from app.module.ts.                                                     export:[progessBar]

Comment: can you share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

If fuse-progress-bar is a component then try importing it i in app.module.ts

```
import { FuseProgressBar } from '../Path';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FuseProgressBar
  ],
  exports: [

  ]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```